# Access value of PHP variable in smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

How can the value of a variable that has been set in PHP be accessed in smarty? My example PHP code is:

```
function searchTwitter() {
    global $smarty;

    $test1 = 'Sometext';
    $smarty->assign("test1", $test1);
    ...
}
```

My .tpl file will have this section:

```
test={$test1}
```

I expect this to display the following in my browser:

```
test=Sometext
```

but it doesn't. Could you please advise how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Seems okay. What is the output?

Comment: Have you included "include('Smarty.class.php');" ?

Comment: You are using function .You need to return a value in php

Comment: Please reffer this sites. http://www.smarty.net/quick_install and http://www.smarty.net/crash_course

Comment: @sroes The output is `test=`

Comment: It should work. Maybe $smarty is redeclared later in the code or the variable gets overwriten somewhere else or you've already executed $smarty->display before calling the function

Answer (score 0):

Actually smarty template engine is use for separate php variable and smarty variable. If you want to use php variable in smarty template you need to assign php variable to smarty through $smarty->assign('smarty variable',php variable);

In smarty there is utility is assign which assign smarty variable to another smarty variable at run time.

or 
{assign varname=varname value=$test1}

now print $varname will print $test1 value

Answer (score -2):

You must use double brackets so try this, it should work:

```
{{$variable}}
```

Hope i was helpfull